# UK standard visit visa refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My application for UK standard visitor visa has been refused because I didn't submit the right bank statement, but I did submit the one where my salary arrives, although my savings are in a different account. Anyways, long story short, we have received a refusal. I wanted to ask what are the chances if I re-apply and get approved (and do submit the complete bank statements this time)? Thanks.

Comment: Can we see a redacted scan of the refusal letter?

Comment: *If* they were only concerned with the missing bank statement, *and* will be satisfied with the ones you submit next time (but we can't know without seeing the refusal letter), your new application should get approved.

Comment: @Henrik but it's almost never is that straightforward which is why scan of refusal letter is a must, not an option.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul: Which is why I emphasised "if" and "and"

Comment: We can't tell you the probability. Partly because you will provide the Immigration Officer with more information than is present in your question. We cannot assess the strength of information that is invisible to us. Any answer such as "Your probability of success is 0.737" is unlikely to be objective or useful to you. It is better to post the refusal letter and ask how to address the points raised.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/13639)